# CSS Title underline

Tags: html, css, styles

I have a CSS linked to a asp.net repeater. What I want is to have the title links underlined on hover and the titles which are not links not to get underlined on mouse hover. 
At the moment I have this in my CSS but both types of titles get underlined.

```
A.TopTitle:link, A.TopTitle:active, A.TopTitle:visited
{

color: #800000;
font-family: Arial;
font-size: 16px;
font-weight: bold;
}

 A.TopTitle, A.TopTitle:hover
{
color: #800000;
font-family: Arial;
font-size: 16px;
font-weight: bold;

}
```

Comment: Change the capital `A` to a small `a` so for example change `A.TopTitle` to `a.TopTitle`

Comment: I can't see any rule related to underlining... :-?

Comment: You're applying the same exact style rules to both sets of selectors. There's also nothing here about `text-decoration`.

Comment: Well, because its part of a CMS the underlines appear automatically. I just need to disable them on the non link titles.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want the following via CSS:
  Things with class="TopTitle" should NOT be underlined
EXCEPT for LINKS when and only on HOVER.

Assuming you have some silly CMS giving inline styling, we'll use !important modifiers..

```
.TopTitle, .TopTitle:link, .TopTitle:active, .TopTitle:visited
{
  text-decoration: none!important;
}
a.TopTitle, a.TopTitle:link, a.TopTitle:active, a.TopTitle:visited
  text-decoration: underline!important;
}
```

I hope I understood you correctly and that this is helpful.

Best of luck.

Comment: Hello msmithgu, yes, you understood correctly. However, your method does not fix it. It just underlines everything and omits the title's format.